# Blank white space where header was

Tags: pages, css

So I'm working on my [website](http://workteamfun.ro/wp2/) and as you see on all the pages there is a white space between the menu and the content on any page. How do I remove this whitespace or hide it?  I think the space was reserved for the page title which I hid on all my pages but that space really bothers me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which white area you mean (the one above the line?) but that can be done by adding the following to your CSS:

```
header.page-header { display:none; }
div.entry-content { margin:0 auto; }
```

Ideally do this in a child theme.

Comment: i used the css code ...and look i am saying the exact white space between the image on the front page and the menu the code for hiding the header cut down a part of the space  ..in other words i am trying to achieve this kind of result on the front page <http://workteamfun.ro/>

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated the CSS, try that one again.

Comment: yeess ...cool man thx a lot :D

Comment: You´re welcome, glad I could help.